# Can our dreams tell us anything useful about ourselves?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, sleep, dreams

This question is related to [What is the current "accepted" science behind dream interpretation?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/643/7001), but here I am asking something more specific.

Dream reports, also known as sleep mentation reports, are a common tool in dream research (eg, [McNamara et al, 2010](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0074-7742(10)92004-7)), which in turn, is mostly useful for learning about dreaming and sleep in general.  However, I am interested in whether such reports could be useful for learning something about the specific individual.  My question therefore is:

**Does there exist a validated instrument that takes dream content (eg, in the form of sleep mentation reports) as input, and using a ([blinded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinded_experiment)) expert analysis or better yet, computer program, predicts something useful at the individual level?**

For example, can dream content predict something about the subject's personality, intelligence, psychopathology, physical health, emotional state, recent events, unresolved problems, life course, or anything else of value, using a validated instrument?

Comment: This is an interesting find. The related question you linked categorically states you cannot accurately interpret dreams into any specific meaning. This was also discussed in my answer at https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2248/7604. But, it is interesting reading through the summarisation put together on the possible uses of sleep mentation reports e.g. determining possible severity of PTSD currently being suffered. Will have to do some digging on this when I get the chance. Will be interesting what comes out of this from others too.